# Java POI occurs InvalidOperationException when using Maven resource filiter

Tags: java, excel, spring, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I have a jar which reads a excel template. If I use Maven shade to package without using resources filter and execute my jar, it is ok; However, I got some exception after I use Maven resources filter! The exception which occurs when I execute jar is as follows:

```
2018-01-05 11:20:45,631 [main] INFO  tw.com.test.aop.SystemPointcuts- AOP Aro
und start : ServiceImpl.ServiceImpl.genExcel(..)(). param : 20171106,20171112
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationE
xception: Can't open the specified file: 'C:\Users\seesaw\AppData\Local\Temp\Wee
klyTelecomAnalysis2553686971923113156.xlsx'
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:131)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:246)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:200)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.ja
va:90)
        at tw.com.test.weeklyTelecomAnalysis.service.ServiceImpl.genExcel(Ser
viceImpl.java:73)
        at tw.com.test.weeklyTelecomAnalysis.service.ServiceImpl$$FastClassBy
SpringCGLIB$$9d7f5cb8.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:2
04)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation
.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.p
roceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
        at tw.com.test.aop.SystemPointcuts.execAround(SystemPointcuts.java:59
)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMet
hodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMet
hod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAro
undAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invok
e(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterce
ptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
        at tw.com.test.weeklyTelecomAnalysis.service.ServiceImpl$$EnhancerByS
pringCGLIB$$1731d8a8.genExcel(<generated>)
        at tw.com.test.weeklyTelecomAnalysis.main.Entry.main(Entry.java:45)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipFile(ZipHelper
.java:157)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:129)
        ... 23 more
```

here's my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tw.com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>WeeklyTelecomAnalysis</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>WeeklyTelecomAnalysis</name>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <pps.datasource>jdbc:oracle:thin:@11.111.11.111:1111:MYPROD</pps.datasource>
                <pps.username>xxxxxx</pps.username>
                <pps.password>xxxxxx</pps.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <!-- 執行類別 -->
        <mainClass>tw.com.test.weeklyTelecomAnalysis.main.Entry</mainClass>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jdk.target.version>1.7</jdk.target.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${jdk.target.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${jdk.target.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <org.springframework.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.osgi</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mybatis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

<!--         <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>poi</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>3.16</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>3.16</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <!-- 安裝ojdbc6.jar至本地maven : mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -->
        <dependency>    
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>    
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>    
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.external</id>
            <name>EBR Libraries Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>WeeklyTelecomAnalysis</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

here's my application-context.xml which is for spring framework and jdbc config, I use Maven resource filter to replace some parameter, but after I do it, I got some error which is as mentioned above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- enable autowiring of components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="tw.com.test" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <!-- MYPROD -->
    <bean id="pps_dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="${pps.datasource}" />
        <property name="username" value="${pps.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${pps.password}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="0" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="180000" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="300" />
        <property name="logAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pps_sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="pps_dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis/sqlMapConfig.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pps_sqlSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="pps_sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pps_stsMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="sqlSessionTemplateBeanName" value="pps_sqlSessionTemplate" />
        <property name="basePackage" value="tw.com.test.weeklyTelecomAnalysis.manual.pps" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

here's the program which read the excel template

```
public XSSFWorkbook genExcel(String fromDate, String toDate) throws Exception {
    // get Excel template
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("excel/WeeklyTelecomAnalysis.xlsx");
    File excel = stream2file(resource.getInputStream(), "WeeklyTelecomAnalysis", ".xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(excel);

    // style
    this.setStyle(workbook);

    XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook.getSheet("WeeklyTelecomAnalysis"); // template
    XSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook.createSheet("detail");

    // start
    createSheet1(sheet1, fromDate, toDate);
    createSheet2(sheet2, fromDate, toDate);

    return workbook;
}
public static File stream2file (InputStream in, String prefix, String suffix) throws IOException {
    final File tempFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    }
    return tempFile;
}
```

could anyone help me?

Comment: what are you trying to do with filtering? are you trying to filter the excel template for some values, or some other files in the folder? it would seem like your .xlsx contains some values that shouldn't be replaced but are replaced by filtering, breaking the file...

Comment: I just want to use "mvn clean package -Pprod"to filter the parameters that are url,username and password in the application-context.xml rather than the excel template. When I execute this jar, I'll get the exception.

Comment: If I set the url, username and password directly and does'nt use maven filter(just use the "mvn clean package" to package my project), there's no any exception when executing the jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem like your .xlsx contains some values that shouldn't be replaced but are replaced by filtering, breaking the file.

> I just want to use "mvn clean package -Pprod"to filter the parameters that are url,username and password in the application-context.xml rather than the excel template.

Given that, just do

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xlsx</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

to only filter your xml configs, leaving your excel template out.

Comment: I still need to use the excel template; However, if I do what you've suggested, the excel template will not be packaged in the jar. I get "java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [e
xcel/WeeklyTelecomAnalysis.xlsx] cannot be opened because it does not exist" when executing jar.

Comment: @FrankHsu sorry about that. I was misleading, I was thinking about adding filtering true only for xml, but didn't mention that you need to include filtering false for others. Updated my answer with explicit settings for both.